# Animating object coming in from side of screen and then back?

Tags: javascript, animation, anime.js

I'm using anime.js to animate several divs from the right side of the screen to where they are defined by the CSS styling. I'm also creating a function to do the reverse, but I'm having several issues.

1. I understand how to animate an object from it's location to a destination by changing translateX, but I can't figure out how to animate moving to it's original location, like with GSAP.from(). I've tried doing this to set the div off the screen while not visible so I could move them back to the original location, but instead it seems to ignore the negative value and just continues moving in one direction.

```
  showAnswerButtons.set(answer_button_array, {translateX: offset_num})
  showAnswerButtons.add({
    targets: answer_button_array,
    translateX: negative_offset_num,
    translateY: negative_offset_num,
    duration: 5000,
    delay: anime.stagger(200)
  });
```

2. As an alternative to the last approach, I've also tried playing an animation to move the divs off the screen, so I could reverse the animation to bring them back. I have 4 divs to animate and sometimes I need to take some of them out of the DOM (Or at least make them invisible). So my plan was to animate them off the screen, change the visibility as needed, then bring back only the ones that I want. Unfortunately using timeline.reverse() doesn't do anything and I've read several stories of people with similar issues. I've also tried setting direction: 'reverse' and then timeline.play() with no success.

Could anyone help me with this code please?

```
<div id="container">
<button id="answer_button_1" class="button"></button>
<button id="answer_button_2" class="button"></button>
<button id="answer_button_3" class="button"></button>
<button id="answer_button_4" class="button"></button>
</div>
```

```
.button {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: black; /*Button Color*/
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```
var hideAnswerButtons;
var showAnswerButtons;

let hidden = true;
document.addEventListener("click", () => {
  hidden = !hidden;
  if (hidden) {
    showAnswerButtons.play();
  } else {
    hideAnswerButtons.play();
  }
});

defineAnimations();
function defineAnimations() {
  let offset_num = 1000;
  let negative_offset_num = -100;
  let answer_button_array = [
    answer_button_4,
    answer_button_3,
    answer_button_2,
    answer_button_1
  ];
  hideAnswerButtons = anime.timeline({ autoplay: false });
  hideAnswerButtons.add({
    targets: answer_button_array,
    translateX: offset_num,
    translateY: offset_num,
    duration: 5000,
    delay: anime.stagger(200),
    easing: 'linear'
  });
  showAnswerButtons = anime.timeline({ autoplay: false });
  //showAnswerButtons.add({
    //targets: answer_button_array,
    //translateX: offset_num,
    //translateY: offset_num,
    //duration: 0,
    //easing: "linear"
  //});
  showAnswerButtons.set(answer_button_array, {translateX: offset_num})
  showAnswerButtons.add({
    targets: answer_button_array,
    translateX: negative_offset_num,
    translateY: negative_offset_num,
    duration: 5000,
    delay: anime.stagger(200),
    easing: 'linear'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse the animation and bring the div to its orginal place you can just use "direction: 'alternate'". Theres more about it in the anime.js documentation:

https://animejs.com/documentation/